# Magento 2 API "self" route: pass customer ID as data parameter

Tags: magento2, customer, api

Let's say I have a custom API endpoint in my module's `etc/webapi.xml` file that should return all the books that belong to the authenticated customer making the request. For example:

```
<route url="/V1/books" method="GET">
    <service class="MyVendor\MyModule\Api\BookInterface" method="getCustomerBooks"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

The method `getCustomerBooks` on the interface `BookInterface`, implemented through the class `Book` require the `$customerId` as the one and only required parameter. The customer making the request doesn't know their customer ID, and has already received an authorization token through the `V1/integration/customer/token` endpoint. The token is included in the HTTP Authorization header of the request, e.g. `Authorization: Bearer [token]`.

The core customer module's `/V1/customers/me` endpoint seems to be doing this by adding a `data` node inside the `route` node:

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

However, when I try adding this to my `route` and make a request, I get an error like:

```
{
  "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "customerId"
  }
}
```

How is the customer module injecting this customer ID as a parameter to the `getById` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The reason for it not working was due to a mismatch in my `getCustomerBooks` method argument name with the name attribute value on the `<parameter />`. The code above works just fine as long as you make sure they match.

Comment: Did you figure out what the `%customer_id%` thing is used for and what it means?

Comment: How was this a solution?

Comment: so, if <resource ref="self"/> is given, the end user should be a customer?
what <resource ref="self"/> is exactly?

Comment: Do you know what  is need of force="true"  in data param ?